# Stringify JSON from SQL Server to return as string

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to return a simple JSON as strings:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('foo')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('bar')

SELECT [value]
FROM @T
FOR JSON PATH
```

What this returns is

```
[{"SS":"foo"},{"SS":"bar"}]
```

What I want is

```
"[{'SS:'foo'},{'SS':'bar'}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want *isn't* valid JSON, it's a quoted string with a JSON like value. You can, however, trivially do this with `REPLACE` and concatenation:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('"',REPLACE((SELECT [value] FROM @T FOR JSON PATH),'"',''''),'"');
```

Comment: What do you recommend than, I need to return the json as a valid string

Comment: What do you mean "as a valid string"..?

Comment: I meant to return the json in string format

Comment: So are you saying the above *doesn't* do that? It returns the same value that is in your question, so if it's not "right" the expected results in your question are wrong.

Comment: The above works

Comment: So I'm not sure what your comments are getting at, I'm afraid.